# Detect p2p from UDP logs

Tags: logging, udp, p2p, torrent

I liked the 4.approach at http://www.brighthub.com/computing/smb-security/articles/48875.aspx - behavioral analysis on how to suspect somebody from using p2p just by having a logger and when infringement email comes, I can find the person in house(10 people, subnet for each flat) to forward it to.

The article says that you should focus on UDP packets from and to one local IP `<->` many different ones, but it is quite old (4 years) and my question is if this is still a valid technique. Google search says that p2p can use both TCP and UDP.

The main reason I'm asking is that my idea was to log **only** UDP traffic, because when logging also TCP, the log file grows like hell(made a file per day and files older than week => /dev/null).

Comment: What is your question? Please add it in your text by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried an experiment on that network with only buffer logging on the main router. I was logging real time UDP. Normally only few udp logs occured per minute(except my experiment when sending email). I tried to start a torrent and watched what happens. I started it and log was totally filled with UDP packets meeting the behavioral analysis conjecture.

Yes, it is still valid technique to at least suspect somebody, if the time of an infingement is equal to time of this behavioral.

And yes, no reason to log TCP traffic(huge data) as for this experiment.